# I am getting NonType error for this python code. How should I change my code?

Tags: python

Why is this code giving me NonType error. Could someone explain me why my variables sluttSek and startSek are being Nontype? Below is my python code.

```
def main():

def mshd2s(minutter, sekunder, hundredeler):
    x = minutter * 60
    z = hundredeler/100

    y = x + sekunder + z

def rundeTid(startTid,sluttTid):
    sluttSek = mshd2s(sluttTid[0],sluttTid[1],sluttTid[2]) 
    startSek = mshd2s(startTid[0],startTid[1],startTid[2]) 
    return sluttSek-startSek


rundeTid([0,45,20],[1,14,55])
```

main()

Answer (score 3):

You need to return a value from `mshd2s`:

```
def mshd2s(minutter, sekunder, hundredeler):
    x = minutter * 60
    z = hundredeler/100

    y = x + sekunder + z
    return y
```

By default a function returns `None` in Python. By returning a value `sluttSek` and `startSek` won't be `None` anymore.